# Sonarqube 5.3 disables DSM during boot

Tags: sonarqube, dependencies

I am running SonarQube 5.3 on linux with mysql 5.5 and Oracle JDK 1.8.0_65. I have a problem getting the dependency cycle report. It all worked fine before the upgrade (don't know the previous version). We generate sonar data with the maven plugin 3.0.1 on Java 1.8 code.

In the sonar log during boot I spotted:

```
2016.01.19 11:35:47 INFO  web[o.s.s.s.RegisterMetrics] Disable metric File dependencies to cut [package_tangles]
2016.01.19 11:35:47 INFO  web[o.s.s.s.RegisterMetrics] Disable metric Package dependencies to cut [package_feedback_edges]
2016.01.19 11:35:47 INFO  web[o.s.s.s.RegisterMetrics] Disable metric Dependency Matrix [dsm]
```

This is basically a out of the box installation. Why is these features disabled and how can I enable them?

Answer (score 1):

Design-related features have been dropped in SonarQube 5.2 (see [SONAR-6553](https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONAR-6553)), which is why you see this message at startup: it tells you that those metrics are now disabled.